# Bootstrap responsive navbar not toggling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using twitter bootstrap for a rails project, and the responsive navbar isn't working quite right. Upon shrinking the screen size, the navbar displays the menu toggle button with the navbar options stuck open below it, and then after further shrinking finally hides the navbar options as it should. However, in either case, clicking the navbar menu toggle button does nothing. I've checked to ensure jQuery is loaded (it is), and that I'm using the newest version of Bootstrap. Here's my code:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{ role: 'navigation', style: 'background-color:#000066' }
    .container
        .navbar-header
            %button.navbar-toggle.pull-right{ type: 'button', data: { toggle: "collapse", target: ".navbar-ex1-collapse" } }
                %span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
            %a.navbar-brand{ href: root_path }
                %strong
                    L
                    %i.fa.fa-cog{ style: 'font-size:80%;margin:0 -2px;' }
                    gSMART
        .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse{ role: 'navigation' }
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                %li
                    %a{ href: root_path, class: set_css_if( path: root_path ) }
                        HOME
                %li
                    %a{ href: about_path, class: set_css_if( path: about_path ) }
                        ABOUT
                %li
                    %a{ href: faq_path, class: set_css_if( path: faq_path ) }
                        FAQs
                %li
                    %a{ href: resources_path, class: set_css_if( path: resources_path ) }
                        MANUALS and RESOURCES
                -if current_user
                    %li
                        %a{ href: logout_path, class: set_css_if( path: logout_path ) }
                            LOGOUT
                -else 
                    %li
                        %a{ href: login_path, class: set_css_if( path: login_path ) }
                            LOGIN
```

For further clarification, here is my layout page, application.js and application.css.

Layout:

```
%html{ lang: :en }
  %head
    %title
      CogSMART
    %meta{ name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" }

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic'
    = stylesheet_link_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true

    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true

    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body.pull_top
    = render 'partials/navbar'
    #coming_soon
      .head
        .container
          .span12.text
            %h4
              CogSMART stands for:
            %h4
              Cognitive Symptom Management and Rehabilitation Therapy
```

app.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree ./clean_canvas
```

app.css

```
/*
 *= require_tree ./clean_canvas_v2
 *= require_self
 */
```

Comment: did you  check the order of script like 1. jquery.js  2. bootstrap.js and then your custom script.

Comment: I checked the script order - here's my app.js: 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree ./clean_canvas

Comment: no errors in console @nicolai, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/hcd377t.png?1 - as you can see, the menu is open, not rolled up like it should be. clicking the toggle button does nothing.

Comment: so i didn't check the javascript console until now, i was thinking you meant the rails console. tons of errors - i added the error message to my post @Nicolai

Comment: It may help to post your source code instead of your ruby on rails code. So we can figure out your JS errors

Comment: i shouldn't need to use requireJs, the asset pipeline loads the javascripts I define with //=require calls. the //=require jquery and jquery-ujs are two different gems that load jquery for use with rails.

Comment: sorry guys, i just realized the jquery errors were because i removed //=require jquery to test a different theory. after putting that line back, i don't get any js console errors at all. what code do you want to see @crazymatt?

Comment: can you also show us generated html code?

Comment: @DanielBogart since you aren't getting JS errors could you post the source code for your menu.

Comment: here's the head: http://i.imgur.com/CsJlet1.png?1
menu code: http://i.imgur.com/BHjlalC.png?1

Comment: this is not an error by anyway: you are loading two times bootstrap.

Comment: and also no need `pull-right` on navbar toggle button...

Comment: thanks @Nicolai, I removed bootstrap.css and left bootstrap.min.css, but obviously the original problem still remains.

Comment: I don't see any error in html... can you try to comment all `css` and `js` files except `jquery` and `bootstrap` and take a look what will happen?

Comment: sure, i'll work on that @Nicolai. here you can see the project yourself, i just deployed it to heroku: https://damp-depths-3602.herokuapp.com/

Comment: the problem still exists even with only boostrap.js, bootstrap.css, and jquery - if i remove jquery, then the menu contracts like it should, but the toggle button still doesn't work. i'll try loading jquery via cdn. edit: same result when loading jquery from cdn. menu collapses when shrinking the page, and opens on click, but doesn't close when clicking a second time.

Comment: I updated the boostrap.js file, and now the menu works correctly when just loading bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css, and jquery. when i add the full directories of js/css, it no longer works. i'll try to isolate the file causing the problem

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with your custom styles.  Unfortunately I can't debug a picture and with the css files being concatenated in heroku it is impossible to see which override rules are causing the problem.  If you really want this solved, create a jsfiddle.net and add your custom css file to the css area.  I can see rules like .navbar-collapse.collapse display: block !important; height: auto !important;  overflow: visible !important; -- any of which could be part of the problem, but I suspect the issues go deeper.

Comment: @jme11 you were exactly right, after removing bootstrap-overrides, the menu worked properly. however, for some reason, now my modal doesn't seem to work. the only other thing i've changed is updating my bootstrap.js file to the current version.

Comment: modal now is covered by overlay, and inputs cannot be clicked. clicking anywhere causes the modal to disappear: http://i.imgur.com/uqfprEs.png?1

Comment: There were some changes to the modal in 3.3.1 both in the css and js files.  If you have an older css file and a newer js file, it could be problematic.

Comment: Nailed it @jme11, css was still older. Thanks a ton for your help, wish I could split the points between you and nicolai.

Comment: No problem.  Got a mortarboard today anyway ;-) Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem code is in css the you loading before bootstrap: about.css, background.css and etc. One of this classes don't allow menu open. - since the css is minified, I don't know in which of the problem lies, but I guess it's in bootstrap-overrides.css.
The wrong css is the following: if you'll remove it navbar should start working:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none
    }

    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a, .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px
    }

    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        background-image: none
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar .collapse {
        display: block !important
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar .navbar-header {
        float: none
    }

    .navbar .navbar-toggle {
        display: block
    }

    .navbar .collapse {
        display: none !important
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 340px;
        overflow-x: visible;
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-y: auto
    }

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav {
        padding: 0px 20px
    }

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
        float: left !important
    }

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav > li {
        float: none
    }

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #999;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 35px;
        font-size: 15px
    }

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: none
    }
}
```

Also you have problem in js files.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have narrowed some of the issues to hopefully get you on the right path. First off I noticed that your menu has this CSS which seems to be causing a lot of problems.

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I would remove all of this. Are you trying to pass `display: hide/block` when the button is selected like the OOTB Bootstrap does?

You will then want to add this property to your CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

And you should take the `!important` off of this class so it looks like this instead.

```
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

So when you load your page the menu should be gone and when you push your button menu button it should load the menu correctly. One thing I did notice is your menu does not remove the `.in` class when clicked for the second time. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ruby is but talking about bootstrap, I see you missed

`data-toggle` which must be written in one phrase with hypen, like this:

```
data-toggle="collapse"
```

or, it maybe:

```
{ type: 'button', class:"navbar-toggle", 
data-toggle: "collapse", data-target: "navbar-ex1-collapse" }
```

Comment: With rails + haml, I don't need to type out the full data-toggle tag for data attributes. data: { toggle: "collapse", target: ".navbar-ex1-collapse" } works fine, which is what I used.

Comment: Thanks, I learn new thing from your question. knowledge is everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the responsive errors you're experiencing are due to CSS not being loaded before JS;

here are some errors I encountered

```
 @media (min-width: 768px)
 .navbar-collapse.collapse
 {display: block !important;}
```

this is why your menu isn't collapsing

Generally you should be able to toogle this class in .in